# why Only one line is getting extended while using brushed() in interactive multiseries line chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am working on a multi-series line chart using d3.js and I am attempting    to implement the focus and context zoom as seen in    http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 .I have       converted the area chart    in the example to a line chart with a single series but I cannot    figure    out why my all lines are not geting extended while extending the x domain    using brush..only x-domain and one line is getting extended as per the new    x domain range....

here is the code i am using......

```
var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 200,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 100
    },
    margin2 = {
        top: 430,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 100
    },
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom,
    legendPanel = {
        width: 80
    },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right - legendPanel.width;

var data = [{
    "symbol": "Banker",
    "date": "20000112",
    "earnedpts": "30",
    "redeemedpts": "15"
}, {
    "symbol": "Banker",
    "date": "20000810",
    "earnedpts": "10",
    "redeemedpts": "8"
}, {
    "symbol": "Banker",
    "date": "20010618",
    "earnedpts": "50",
    "redeemedpts": "20"
}, {
    "symbol": "Banker",
    "date": "20011220",
    "earnedpts": "40",
    "redeemedpts": "20"
}, {
    "symbol": "Banker",
    "date": "20020220",
    "earnedpts": "30",
    "redeemedpts": "20"
}, {
    "symbol": "Banker",
    "date": "20021130",
    "earnedpts": "10",
    "redeemedpts": "5"
}, {
    "symbol": "Health",
    "date": "20000112",
    "earnedpts": "20",
    "redeemedpts": "15"
}, {
    "symbol": "Health",
    "date": "20000810",
    "earnedpts": "40",
    "redeemedpts": "28"
}, {
    "symbol": "Health",
    "date": "20010618",
    "earnedpts": "30",
    "redeemedpts": "20"
}, {
    "symbol": "Health",
    "date": "20011220",
    "earnedpts": "60",
    "redeemedpts": "35"
}, {
    "symbol": "Health",
    "date": "20020220",
    "earnedpts": "30",
    "redeemedpts": "25"
}, {
    "symbol": "Health",
    "date": "20021130",
    "earnedpts": "20",
    "redeemedpts": "15"
}, {
    "symbol": "Govt",
    "date": "20000112",
    "earnedpts": "80",
    "redeemedpts": "65"
}, {
    "symbol": "Govt",
    "date": "20000810",
    "earnedpts": "60",
    "redeemedpts": "48"
}, {
    "symbol": "Govt",
    "date": "20010618",
    "earnedpts": "60",
    "redeemedpts": "40"
}, {
    "symbol": "Govt",
    "date": "20011220",
    "earnedpts": "30",
    "redeemedpts": "15"
}, {
    "symbol": "Govt",
    "date": "20020220",
    "earnedpts": "40",
    "redeemedpts": "25"
}, {
    "symbol": "Govt",
    "date": "20021130",
    "earnedpts": "30",
    "redeemedpts": "5"
}, {
    "symbol": "BPO",
    "date": "20000112",
    "earnedpts": "70",
    "redeemedpts": "45"
}, {
    "symbol": "BPO",
    "date": "20000810",
    "earnedpts": "60",
    "redeemedpts": "30"
}, {
    "symbol": "BPO",
    "date": "20010618",
    "earnedpts": "40",
    "redeemedpts": "25"
}, {
    "symbol": "BPO",
    "date": "20011220",
    "earnedpts": "70",
    "redeemedpts": "50"
}, {
    "symbol": "BPO",
    "date": "20020220",
    "earnedpts": "40",
    "redeemedpts": "25"
}, {
    "symbol": "BPO",
    "date": "20021130",
    "earnedpts": "50",
    "redeemedpts": "30"
}];

var parsedate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
x2 = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x2)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#04b0ff", "#04ffa8", "#ff5404", "#8a89a6", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed);

var extent = brush.extent();
var rangeExtent = [x2(extent[0]), x2(extent[1])];
var rangeWidth = rangeExtent[1] - rangeExtent[0];

var priceline1 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.earnedpts);
    })
    .interpolate("linear");

var priceline2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.redeemedpts);
    })
    .interpolate("linear");

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + legendPanel.width)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")")
    .attr("class", "context");

svg.append("defs")
    .append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parsedate(d.date);
    d.earnedpts = +d.earnedpts;
    d.redeemedpts = +d.redeemedpts;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
}));
x2.domain(x.domain());
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return Math.max(d.earnedpts, d.redeemedpts);
})]);
y2.domain(y.domain());

var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.symbol;
    })
    .entries(data);

dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
    focus.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", function() {
            return d.color = color(d.key);
        })
        .attr("d", priceline1(d.values))
});

dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
    focus.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", function() {
            return d.color = color(d.key);
        })
        .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
        .attr("d", priceline2(d.values))
});

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis1")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

var contextArea = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) {
        return x2(d.date);
    })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(0);

context.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", contextArea(dataNest[0].values))
    .attr("fill", "#F1F1F2");

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", height2)
    .attr("fill", "#E6E7E8");

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", -30)
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Days");

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Average points Earned & Redeemed");


dataNest.forEach(function(d, i) {
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + "," + y(data[dataNest[i].values.length + i * 6 - 1].earnedpts) + ")")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .style("fill", function() {
            return d.color = color(d.key);
        })
        .text(d.key);
});

focus.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 20) + ",5)")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .text("Points Earned");

focus.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 20) + "," + (y(data[0].redeemedpts) - 245) + ")")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .text("Points Redeemed");

function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focus.select(".x.axis").transition().call(xAxis);
    focus.select(".y.axis").transition().call(yAxis);
    dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
        focus.selectAll("path")
            .style("stroke", function() {
                return d.color = color(d.key);
            })
            .transition()
            .attr("d", priceline1(d.values))
    });
}
```

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle link     http://jsfiddle.net/vmehz2fg/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some issues here.

First you create two types of lines (dashed and solid) using two different line methods. That is fine. However, in the update method at the end, you select all of them and use only one drawing method (`priceline`). I would propose the following changes:

1. Add a class indentifier to each line, such as `line1`, or `line2` as follows:

   ```
   dataNest.forEach(function (d) {
    focus.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line line1-" + d.key)
      .style("stroke", function () {
      return color(d.key);
    })
   .attr("d", priceline1(d.values));
   });
   ```

   and

   ```
   dataNest.forEach(function (d) {
    focus.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line line2-" + d.key)
      .style("stroke", function () {
     return color(d.key);
   })
   .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
   .attr("d", priceline2(d.values));
   });
   ```
2. Then, on your brush event, select the appropirate one and update the line. (Apologies, I don' t know exactly which one you want to update so I have included them both)

   ```
   function brushed() {
       x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
       focus.select(".x.axis").transition().call(xAxis);
       focus.select(".y.axis").transition().call(yAxis);
       dataNest.forEach(function (d) {
           focus.selectAll(".line1-" + d.key)
               .transition().duration(200)
               .attr("d", priceline1(d.values));
           focus.selectAll(".line2-" + d.key)
               .transition().duration(200)
               .attr("d", priceline2(d.values));
       });

   }
   ```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bu6wzjv0/).

Regarding your scale format, you can use the `tickFormat` method as follows:

```
// First define a formatting method such as
var axisFormat = d3.time.format("%b")

// Then apply your tickFormat to your scale
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("bottom")
                  .tickFormat(function(d) {
                      v=axisFormat(d); 
                      return v.substr(0,1) // you can adjust this.
                   });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: one more doubt  i have..here i am using time scale() for x axis.so i am getting "2000 April July....." in x axis...but my requirement is to get "2000 F   M A M J J A S O N D 2001 F"....so on in x axis..so how can i get the first letter of each month's name in x axis ???

Comment: Hi, I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: Thanks Nikos...but what i exactly want is  the first letter of name of months with year boundary like "2000 F M A M J J A S O N D 2001 F.....so on"...but if i will use any function in tickFormat() of xaxis, i wont get the year boundary like  "J F M A M J J A S O N D.."...wat only i get is month's name

Comment: Can anyone help me with the code for getting the above format(first letter of month's name with year boundary) in x-axis.....i have tried my best but not able to get this format...

Comment: I don't think this is doable.